# How to get minus off to the the difference?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to find the available seat. I try using the following code, to get the total row after that minus the value at capacity. But it fails to do so. May I know what is the correct way to do it ?

```
 SELECT r.Route_No, s.Serial_No, s.Flight_Fly_On, a.Capacity, (Capacity - (count(*) FROM scheduled) AS Available_Seat
    FROM Route r, Scheduled s, Airplane a
    WHERE s.Serial_No = a.Serial_No
    AND r.Route_No = s.Route_No;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: So sorry, I think i tag wrongly. It should be oarcle sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `SCHEDULED` table counts when a person is scheduled on a particular flight and that you can uniquely identify a flight using the route, airplane's serial number and the flight date then you can us an analytic `COUNT` function (rather than using a sub-query):

```sql
SELECT r.Route_No,
       s.Serial_No,
       s.Flight_Fly_On,
       a.Capacity,
       a.Capacity - COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.route_no, s.serial_no, s.flight_fly_on)
         AS Available_Seat
FROM   Route r
       INNER JOIN Scheduled s
       ON (r.Route_No = s.Route_No)
       INNER JOIN Airplane a
       ON (s.Serial_No = a.Serial_No);
```

If you did want to use a sub-query then you need to correlate it to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT r.Route_No,
       s.Serial_No,
       s.Flight_Fly_On,
       a.Capacity,
       a.Capacity - (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM   Scheduled c
                     WHERE  s.route_no      = c.route_no
                     AND    s.serial_no     = c.serial_no
                     AND    s.flight_fly_on = c.flight_fly_on)
         AS Available_Seat
FROM   Route r
       INNER JOIN Scheduled s
       ON (r.Route_No = s.Route_No)
       INNER JOIN Airplane a
       ON (s.Serial_No = a.Serial_No);
```

If it is not the `SCHEDULED` table that holds details of a person's bookings but it is, for example, the `BOOKINGS` table then you are using the wrong table and need to count from the correct table:

```sql
SELECT r.Route_No,
       s.Serial_No,
       s.Flight_Fly_On,
       a.Capacity,
       a.Capacity - (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM   Bookings b
                     WHERE  b.scheduled_no = s.scheduled_no)
         AS Available_Seat
FROM   Route r
       INNER JOIN Scheduled s
       ON (r.Route_No = s.Route_No)
       INNER JOIN Airplane a
       ON (s.Serial_No = a.Serial_No);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test the following query.
I have normalised the JOIN conditions, specified that we are counting the schedule table, and added GROUP BY.
I have also added the column `count(s.Route_No) AS seats_booked` so that, if the query doesn't return the expected results you can check whether the COUNT() is correct. This will help find the problem if there is one.

```
SELECT 
  r.Route_No, 
  s.Serial_No, 
  s.Flight_Fly_On, 
  a.Capacity AS total_seats, 
  COUNT(s.Route_No) AS seats_booked
  (a.Capacity - (count(s.Route_No) FROM scheduled) AS Available_Seats
FROM Route r 
JOIN Scheduled s ON r.Route_No = s.Route_No
JOIN Airplane a on s.Serial_No = a.Serial_No
GROUP BY
  r.Route_No, 
  s.Serial_No, 
  s.Flight_Fly_On, 
  a.Capacity ;
```